# Which one? Node-jws or node-jsonwebtoken?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, express-jwt

There are two packages for JWT application in Node.js .But uses same method for signing and verifying .  Which one is for production purpose ?

Comment: This is a matter of preference. There aren't just two, there are a lot more. It's like the wild west out there. When looking for libraries to use think about 1.) does it fulfill your need 2.) is it trustworthy 3.) is it secure 4.) is it maintained. There are probably more but you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks You!!! :) @DillanWilding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both suitable for use in production. `jsonwebtoken` uses the `jws` package for the signing. Which one you use depends on what you want: signatures or tokens.